Whitelabel Error Page: 404 Not Found Issue in Spring Boot Docker Application
OS-Details:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

code
Main file(Startup.java)
package com.baeldung.spring_project;

import io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.config.EnableR2dbcRepositories;
import org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.R2dbcTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.ReactiveTransactionManager;

import java.beans.BeanProperty;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Startup.class, args);
    }

    @BeanProperty
    public ReactiveTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    }

}

Controller file(ZipCodeApi.java)
package com.baeldung.spring_project;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.baeldung.spring_project.domain.ZIPRepo;
import com.baeldung.spring_project.domain.ZipCode;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.r2dbc.UncategorizedR2dbcException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/zipcode")
public class ZipCodeApi {

    @Autowired
    private ZIPRepo zipRepo;

    public ZipCodeApi(ZIPRepo zipRepo) {
        this.zipRepo = zipRepo;
    }

    // Unique mapping for findById
    @GetMapping("/{zipcode}")
    public Mono<ZipCode> findById(@PathVariable String zipcode) {
        return zipRepo.findById(zipcode);
    }

    @GetMapping("/city")
    public Flux<ZipCode> findByCity(@RequestParam String city) {
        return zipRepo.findByCity(city);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<ZipCode> create(@RequestBody ZipCode zipCode) {
        return zipRepo.findById(zipCode.getZip())
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(createZipCode(zipCode)))
                .onErrorResume(this::isKeyDuplicated, this.recoverWith(zipCode));
    }

    // Method to handle creation of new ZIP code
    private Supplier<Mono<? extends ZipCode>> createZipCode(ZipCode zipCode) {
        return () -> {
            zipCode.setId(zipCode.getZip());
            return zipRepo.save(zipCode);
        };
    }

    private boolean isKeyDuplicated(Throwable ex) {
        return ex instanceof DataIntegrityViolationException || ex instanceof UncategorizedR2dbcException;
    }

    private Function<? super Throwable, ? extends Mono<ZipCode>> recoverWith(ZipCode zipCode) {
        return throwable -> zipRepo.findById(zipCode.getZip());
    }
}

Compose file(Spring.yml)
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.38
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: baeldung
      MYSQL_USER: nikhil
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: nikhil123
    command: [ 'mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci' ]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "127.0.0.1", "-u", "nikhil", "--password=nikhil123"] 
    volumes:
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
  app:
      image: docker.io/library/spring-project:0.1-SNAPSHOT
      ports:
        - '8080:8080'
      environment:
        DB_URL: r2dbc:mysql://db:3306/baeldung?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
        HOST_HOSTNAME: ${EXTERNAL_IP}
      depends_on:
        db:
          condition: service_healthy
      deploy:
        resources:
          limits:
            cpus: '3.00'

I added the data into my DB and tried with this URL "localhost:8080/zipcode/by_city?city=New%20York" but here I am facing 500 Internal Server Error.
#Udated Logs
"nikhil@nikhil-Latitude-7480:~/tutorials/quarkus-modules/quarkus-vs-springboot/spring-project/src/main/docker$ docker-compose up
Attaching to docker-app-1, docker-db-1

docker-app-1  | Setting Active Processor Count to 4
docker-app-1  | Calculating JVM memory based on 12669348K available memory
docker-app-1  | For more information on this calculation, see https://paketo.io/docs/reference/java-reference/#memory-calculator
docker-app-1  | Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx12276406K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=85741K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 12669348K, Thread Count: 50, Loaded Class Count: 12724, Headroom: 0%)
docker-app-1  | Enabling Java Native Memory Tracking
docker-app-1  | Adding 137 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
docker-app-1  | Spring Cloud Bindings Enabled
docker-app-1  | Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=4 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx12276406K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=85741K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true
docker-app-1  | 
docker-app-1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
docker-app-1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
docker-app-1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
docker-app-1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
docker-app-1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
docker-app-1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
docker-app-1  | 
docker-app-1  |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.3)
docker-app-1  | 
docker-app-1  | 
docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:19:27.687Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.baeldung.spring_project.Startup      : Starting Startup using Java 17.0.7 with PID 1 (/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes started by cnb in /workspace)
docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:19:27.693Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.baeldung.spring_project.Startup      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:19:29.044Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data R2DBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:19:29.345Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 282 ms. Found 1 R2DBC repository interfaces.
docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:19:31.443Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.baeldung.spring_project.domain.ZIPRepo
docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:19:32.194Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:19:32.212Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.baeldung.spring_project.Startup      : Started Startup in 5.333 seconds (process running for 6.14)
**docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:23:02.415Z  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.baeldung.spring_project.ZipCodeApi
docker-app-1  | 2024-09-16T11:24:03.129Z ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [b08b1ffd-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/zipcode/by_city?city=New%20York"**
docker-app-1  | 
docker-app-1  | org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection
docker-app-1  |     at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.lambda$getConnection$0(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90) ~[spring-r2dbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
docker-app-1  |     Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
docker-app-1  | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
docker-app-1  |     *__checkpoint ? Handler com.baeldung.spring_project.ZipCodeApi#findById(String) [DispatcherHandler]
docker-app-1  |     *__checkpoint ? HTTP GET "/zipcode/by_city?city=New%20York" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
docker-app-1  | Original Stack Trace:
docker-app-1  |         at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.lambda$getConnection$0(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90) ~[spring-r2dbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Mono.java:3783) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.onError(FluxRetry.java:95) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:475) ~[reactor-pool-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:433) ~[reactor-pool-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onError(MonoSubscribeOn.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.netty.resources.NewConnectionProvider$DisposableConnect.onError(NewConnectionProvider.java:154) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:576) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.setFailure(TransportConnector.java:522) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
docker-app-1  |         at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$doConnect$7(TransportConnector.java:261) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$2.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:614) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:416) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
docker-app-1  | Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: db/172.20.0.2:3306
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$2.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:613) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:416) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
docker-app-1  |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
docker-app-1  | 
docker-app-1  | 

You’re seeing a 500 Internal Server Error in your Spring Boot application after updating the schema.sql file to insert data into the zipcode table. The application fails to connect to the MySQL database, with logs showing a timeout error (connection timed out: db/172.31.0.2:3306).

To me, it seems like all mappings starts with `/zipcode/, hence you should use e.g. http://localhost:8080/zipcode/city?city=

Thank you for your feedback. You’re right that all mappings start with /zipcode/, so localhost:8080/zipcode/city?city= is correct.
However, I don’t have access to the MySQL database to check the available city names. I’m working on this project from GitHub and am currently trying to run it using Docker Compose commands.
Let me know if there's anything else I can try to get it up and running.

If you don't insert any data into the db during app startup, your db will be empty.

I added the data into my DB and then I tried with this URL "http://localhost:8080/zipcode/by_city?city=New%20York" but here  I am facing 500 Internal Server Error.

You should add the stacktrace from the 500-error to your question. BR

I updated it, sir.
